# display BLOCK inside SECTION

Tags: html, css

I have three sections one beside one another using inline-flex.  Inside my third section, I would like to have my checkboxes one underneath the other.

```css
.partOne section {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.checkbox section {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="partOne">
  <section>
    <label>name: </label>
    <label class="lblName">Jessica</label>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label class="lblAds">Pet:</label>
  </section>
  <section class="checkbox">
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="Dog">
      <label for="checkbox">Dog</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="Cat">
      <label for="checkbox">Cat</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="Bird">
      <label for="checkbox">Bird</label>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

But I can't get my checkboxes one below the other.

Comment: At the interest of [semantics](https://www.lifewire.com/why-use-semantic-html-3468271), perhaps those inner `section`s should be `div`s instead?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Matt. You're misusing the `<section>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn`.chekbox` into a flex element and give it `flex-direction: column`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="partOne">
  <section>
    <label>name: </label>
    <label class="lblName">Jessica</label>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label class="lblAds">Pet:</label>
  </section>
  <section class="checkbox">
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="Dog">
      <label for="checkbox">Dog</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="Cat">
      <label for="checkbox">Cat</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="Bird">
      <label for="checkbox">Bird</label>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

If you also want to have the `Name` and `Pet` in one line, you can give `.partOne` `display: inline-flex`, which can be seen here:

```css
.partOne {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="partOne">
  <section>
    <label>name: </label>
    <label class="lblName">Jessica</label>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label class="lblAds">Pet:</label>
  </section>
  <section class="checkbox">
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="Dog">
      <label for="checkbox">Dog</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="Cat">
      <label for="checkbox">Cat</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="Bird">
      <label for="checkbox">Bird</label>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.checkbox` section a flex-column.

```css
.partOne section {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="partOne">
  <section>
    <label>name: </label>
    <label class="lblName">Jessica</label>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label class="lblAds">Pet:</label>
  </section>
  <section class="checkbox">
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="Dog">
      <label for="checkbox">Dog</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="Cat">
      <label for="checkbox">Cat</label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="Bird">
      <label for="checkbox">Bird</label>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would mention that your labels are incorrect too. The "for" needs to point to an ID..... It should look more like this. I added the role for ADA and tabindex so it works with the space bar.

```
 <section>
    <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" id="box3" name="Bird" value="Bird">
    <label for="box3">Bird</label>
</section>
```